# Convert byte array to different data types

Tags: java, arrays, string, types, utf-8

I need to identify the proper data type of a variable from a `byte[]`.

**Use case**

From the client-side data of different parameters are received by the server. The server collects the data as `byte[]`. Then it converts to a `String`. The ultimate target is to identify the correct data type from that `String`. The target data type can be any of these `{String, Integer, Long, Float, Double, Boolean, Timestamp, JSON Object, Array, etc.}`.

Currently, the following code snippet is used to convert the `byte[]` to `String`.

```
...
byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
dataBuffer.read(bytes);
String value = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Datatype datatype = getDataTypeFromString(value); // Datatype and getDataTypeFromString are user-defined Class and function respectively
```

The problem with the above implementation is that we may lose the original information while converting the `byte[]` to `String` as `UTF_8` doesn't have support for certain characters. The following code snippet indicates that **behavior**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Code to convert byte arr to str:
    byte[] originalByteArr = {0,1,-2,3,-4,-5,6};
    String str1 = new String(originalByteArr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("str1 >> "+str1);

    // Code to convert str to byte arr:
    byte[] newByteArr = str1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    for(int i=0;i<newByteArr.length;i++) {
        System.out.printf(newByteArr[i] +" ");
    }
}
//You will see that the originalByteArr and newByteArr are different
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: It isn't really true that UTF-8 doesn't have support for certain characters, but it is certainly possible to have a illegal sequence of bytes that don't make up valid UTF-8. The question is, what would you like your program to do with that invalid data? What result should be obtained?

Comment: I am not sure whether the end user of my application can generate such illegal data. But, the primary concern of mine is that if we convert the byte[] to String, will we lose any information or data? @DavidConrad

Comment: Well, that's pretty important information. How does the data get generated and what is it supposed to contain?

Comment: The API is kind of generic with support of content-type `mutipart/form-data`. So in this API all kinds of data (binary data in case of file, or any string, dates etc) can be passed. The server receives everything as byte array and later it tries to convert the byte array to the target data type. Do I need to share any other info? @DavidConrad

Answer (score 0):

A fair comparison would be

```
      byte[] originalByteArr = {0, 1, -2, 3, -4, -5, 6};
      String str1 = new String(originalByteArr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      System.out.println("str1 >> " + str1);

      byte[] newByteArr = str1.getBytes();
      String str2 = new String(newByteArr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      System.out.println("str2 >> " + str2);
```

OR

```
      byte[] originalByteArr = "{0,1,-2,3,-4,-5,6}".getBytes();
      String str1 = new String(originalByteArr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      System.out.println("str1 >> " + str1);

      byte[] newByteArr = str1.getBytes();
      String str2 = new String(newByteArr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      System.out.println("str2 >> " + str2);
```

Comment: Are we reading the same question? I don't see any `int[]` or any serializing or deserializing happening.

Comment: I removed the explanation to keep the focus on the point. But that doesn't change the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does not appear to be a good idea as you will be lose information if you rely on the mapping of `byte[]` to `String` for certain ranges of values.

Consider these two `byte[4]` conversions which show that there is not a 1:1 mapping - both map to same `String`:

```
String a = new String(new byte[]{1,2,3, -128}, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String b = new String(new byte[]{1,2,3, -127}, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(a.equals(b));
// prints true
```

Comment: Thanks for sparing some time on this. Can you please guide me what to do then?

Comment: Client / server communications don't work unless end points have some agreed format convention - such as a structure (eg XML / JSON / YAML/ Java Serialisation), or meta-data (eg content-type JPG / PNG), and other encoding information (eg ZIP / Base64) which should tell you precisely about how you decode the underlying byte[] stream back to a usable format in your receiver.